# .Net-Core get HttpBrowserCapabilities from httpContext

Tags: asp.net-core, httpcontext

I want to use the `HttpBrowserCapabilities` in .net-core. I tried it following way:

```
var userAgent = httpContext.Request.Headers["user-agent"];
var userBrowser = new HttpBrowserCapabilities { Capabilities = new Hashtable { { string.Empty, userAgent } } };
var factory = new BrowserCapabilitiesFactory();
factory.ConfigureBrowserCapabilities(new NameValueCollection(), userBrowser);
var mobileString = userBrowser.IsMobileDevice ? "(mobil)" : string.Empty;
var browserString = $"{userBrowser.Browser} version {userBrowser.Version} {mobileString} OS: {userBrowser.Platform}";
```

But an InvalidCastException is thrown. How ca i get this code retun the right values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got it!**

userAgent is of the type `Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues`.
But `HttpBrowserCapabilities` expects a string as input parameter.

Therefore i had to check if `userAgent` contains a value (`userAgent.Any()`) and use the following code

```
var userBrowser = new HttpBrowserCapabilities {Capabilities = new Hashtable {{string.Empty, userAgent.First()}}};
```

Comment: Rather than `ToArray()[0]` would `First()` not work?